# Problem with webrtc, I can not connect per call in localhost

Tags: node.js, webrtc

iam using webrtc-voice demo from tutorialspoint using nodejs its working fine in my file path but its not working in localhost it shows upgarde required error

if anyone know about this error please provide the solution

Comment: Does your server.js has http.createServer call ?

Comment: yes ,i created http.createServer call and my server.js is

Comment: Here is the sourcecode i am using - https://gist.github.com/karthikbr82/96648632019a636ebd2ce27f1b521b54